# ServiceStack AuthFeature.HtmlRedirect being ignored

Tags: authentication, servicestack

When I set the authentication feature redirect property it is not being applied when I go to access a secure page.
For example I set the authentication feature to redirect to use a custom log in page.

```
authFeature.HtmlRedirect = "http://localhost/SimpleService/login";
```

But if I go to a secure controller, this redirect is never being applied it always uses the service stack default of **"/login"**. The redirect it is using does not even include the originating site name of SimpleService. Sample controller below.

```
[Authenticate]
public class PrivateController : ControllerBase
{
    public ViewResult SecurePage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have also tried to override the the redirect on the Authenticate attribute, but to no avail. Has anyone any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
[Authenticate(HtmlRedirect = "http://localhost/SimpleService/login")]
public class PrivateController : ControllerBase
{
    public ViewResult SecurePage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I got the same issues as above.  A work around I found is to override the LoginRedirectUrl in your base controller.  This worked for me.

eg

```
public override string LoginRedirectUrl
{
    get
    {
        return "/Account/Login?redirect={0}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I was going bananas with this issue.